# Why is it that when I move my text down another vertical scroll bar appears on the inside of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why is it that when I move my text down another vertical scroll bar appears on the inside of the browser its right where then width ends at approximately 1000px is there a way to extend the length of my page or a simple way to hide the scroll bar that is showing vertically? I still want the default browser vertical scroll bar to show.  All tips are appreciated thank you![image: scroll bar]

If you need to seen any of my code just ask thanks again!
HTML:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Iamdrivingtoday.com </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mfcc.css">

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.vegas.min.css"></link>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#fadein {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}


-->
</style>


</head>

<body>
        <div id="big_wrapper">
            <header id="top_header">
                <img src="iadt.jpg" height="100" width="300"> </img>
            </header>

            <center><nav id="top_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Application">Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>  </center>

                <div class="fadein">

    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -90px;">
    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -90px;">
    <img src="images/slide.jpg"  width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -90px;">   
</div>

<div class="bg1">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -125px; top: 477px;">

</div>

<img src="Images/images/newcar.png" width=150 height=150 style="position: relative; top: 320px; left: 100px">



<img src="Images/images/usedcar.png" width=150 height=150 style="position: relative; top: 320px; left: 500px">
<section id="new_car">

            <center> <h3>New Car Loan Requirements</h3> </center>

        <p> If you're ready to apply for a new car loan, fill out our quick an easy application here at
        Iamdrivingtoday.com  But obviously, you don't want to waste your time when you don't 
        know the requirements to get approved for a new car loan.  Here's what you'll need to qualify:
        </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
$.vegas('next');
});
</script>           

    <section id="main_section" style="position: relative; right: 0px;">
        <article>
        <header>
             <hgroup>
                <center><h1>What is Iamdrivingtoday.com?</h1></center>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
            <p>Iamdrivingtoday.com is where we specialize in providing auto loans for people with bad credit. 
            We know that new and used car customers in certain times need help
            finding the right auto loan provider. If you think you 
            have a really bad, or low credit rating, or you have been
            turned down in the past, chances are we can help!  
            Our specialty is getting you financed and we guarantee an
            approval!</p>
        </article>
        <article>
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                <center><h1>Having a hard time getting approved?</h1></center>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
            <p>No matter what your prior credit which may be due to bankruptcy, divorce, 
            foreclosure, repossession, late payments, or unpaid balances we get
            you driving the same day no matter your circumstances.
            Just fill out the application and drive away today.</p>
        </article> 
    </section>

    <div id="new_div">

    <aside id="side_news">
        <h4>What your Dealer needs!</h4>
        <center>Paystubs!</center>
        <center>$1000 Down!</center>
        <center>Proof of Insurance!</center>
    </aside>


</body>



</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h1{
    font:bold 16px tahoma;
}
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
    display: block;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}
section{
    font: 12px Verdana;
}
#big_wrapper{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
#top_header{
    background: transparent;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#top_menu{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #BDBDBD, #E6E6E6, #BDBDBD);
    width: 998px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
#top_menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
}
#new_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}
#new_car{
 Position: relative;
 Top: 20px
}
#bg1{
border: 3px solid black;
}

#main_section{
    Position: relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
     2px 2px 0 #000,  
      1px 1px 0 #000;
    background-image:url('tb.png');
    background-size: 365px 325px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    float: right;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-right: 625px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

#side_news{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #66CCCC;
}
#the_footer{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Any link/code/jsfiddle to show us?

Comment: thats all the code I have, I dont what part of code would individually cause this issue?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do `overflow-x: hidden` or `overflow-y: hidden` at all. If you are doing it, you are just `making things work somehow.`

Comment: I don't see any problem in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/V5RXQ/2/show/

Answer (score 3):

Best guess without seeing code: You have a set height on that container element with overflow:auto

Edit: After looking at your code, I think the best thing to do in this situation is to encourage you to spend some more time reading up about HTML and CSS. You have a lot of inline styles and you're positioning things that really mess up the natural flow of the document. This isn't a small error that's happening but just fundamentally poor code.

I'm not saying this to be mean, but this scroll bar is the least of your problems.

Comment: This is my first real time coding so I know there is some errors and as far as my inline styles im still learning to make them external.

Answer (score 0):

By default when your contents height or width exceeds the height or width of the container explicitly set by you, the css properties `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` are enabled.

Disabling the overflow-y value on that particular element will remove the scrollbar.

```
overflow-y:hidden
```

To avoid the content from being clipped, increase the height of the container or reduce the content or vice-versa. Not setting the height explicitly or setting it to auto will ensure the container expands enough to prevent its contents from overflowing.

**[DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-xy)**

Comment: actually, by default the overflow is set to `visible` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), and the container should grow along with its content. He is probably setting a fixed width / height somewhere, which is imo the root of the problem...

Comment: Thats what i said, If you set the height and width explicitly yourself. Okay i've just removed the ambiguity by adding it.

Comment: I already have overflow-x: Hidden I am trying to keep the the other vertical scrollbar this scrollbar is within the page that im trying to get rid of.

Comment: I dont believe that I have a height set in the container.

Answer (score -1):

You should use,

overflow-y:hidden; - Use this for hiding the Vertical scroll

overflow-x:auto; - Use this to show Horizontal scroll

For IE8: -ms-overflow-y: hidden;

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: im not looking to hide the vertical, and my slideshow goes beyond the page that is why I have the horizontal hidden so my slideshows stay centered. Thank you for the response though!